# Computed dependencies in make pattern rules

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

With this simplified example `Makefile`

```
PHONY: all
all: prog_main

prog_main.c:
    echo 'int module(); int main(){return module();}' > $@

module.c:
    echo 'int module(){return 0;}' > $@

main_objects := module.o

prog_%: prog_%.o $(%_objects)
    $(CC) -o $@ $< $($*_objects)
```

a `make` will fail, because

- the syntax `$(%_objects)` is not supported by make and ignored,
- `module.o` is not a dependency of `prog_main`,
- make sees no need to compile `module.o`, and
- the link fails, because there is no `module.o`.

Is there a way to tell make, that each `prog_%` depends on `prog_%.o` and the targets listed int the variable `%_objects`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do what your describing as make expands `%` and variables at different times during processing.   But you could replace the line: `main_objects := module.o` with `prog_main: modules.o`.    If you did that, then `module.o` would appear in `$^` in the `prog_%:` recipes.   So you would have something like:

```
.PHONY: all
all: prog_main

prog_main.c:
    echo 'int module(); int main(){return module();}' > $@

module.c:
    echo 'int module(){return 0;}' > $@

# main_objects := module.o
prog_main: module.o


prog_%: prog_%.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $^
```